# Game Maker doesn't refresh files after a git update

Tags: git, game-maker

When a I use Git in GameMaker, update doesn't refresh the project view, I have to restart the soft to see new items. I have configured SCM with : http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/101983386-SCM-Part-6a-Configurations-for-GIT A friend did it the same way as me but it works for him
Ha and : I using GameMaker : Studio Pro with Windows 10, my version of Git is : 1.9.5.msysgit.1.

Comment: Do you have checked `Always reload changed files` option at `Preferences` -> `General`?

Comment: Yes i have, it's checked. But same problem. Event if I use TortoiseGit, project view doesn't refresh.

Comment: are you refresning from GM (internally), or outside of ?

Comment: I use the internal SCM of GMS, but apparently it's a know bug.In the next update it will be resolve ^^